# Rails: How to prevent autocomplete results showing up in erb?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I implemented an autocomplete function on a form field and it is working fine.

This is my **add_diploma.html.erb**:

```
<%= f.fields_for :keywords do |words| %>
    <li>
        <%= words.label "Keyword : " %>
        <%= words.text_field :keywords, class:"field_motsclef", data: {autocomplete_source: keywords_enum_path} %> 
    </li>
<% end %>
```

The point is that when the text field is being filled out, the proposed terms appear in the field, BUT in the same time at the bottom of the page.

I guess this is due to the fact that `data: { autocomplete_source: keywords_enum_path }` appears within the `<%=` tag.

As per the documentation, the complex forms do require the `<%=` tag though : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

How can I prevent the result of `data: {autocomplete_source: keywords_enum_path}` to be displayed?

Thanks